# Unwanted Wordpress URL Redirect

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

When trying to change Wordpress URLs from site/category/foo/ to site/blog/foo/ the resulting pages redirects to (an existing) site/foo/. What could be causing this?

Comment: Do you have redirect plugin installed, It redirects old slug to new slug

Comment: @SudharshanNair Nope, I don't have that plugin.

Comment: Can you also show your htaccess